# SDK 6.1 UITextAlignment error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, compiler-errors

I have a project writed under iOS6, that is compliant with iOS5 or plus. Recently I re-open the project and I have this very strange error

[image]

But in all my other project this line work fine.
What is the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: @rmaddy: oh sorry.. I just changed Deployment Target.So it fixed my issue.. If it not make sense, Im going to delete my answer. thanks .. I pasted your comment below to help Fry.. :)

Comment: That doesn't matter in this case. You need to use the constants available in your Base SDK (most likely 6.1 based on your title), not the Deployment Target. The newer NSTextAlignment constants are backward compatible with the older UITextAlignment constants as long as you only use Left, Center, or Right. – rmaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The older `UITextAlignment` enum was deprecated in iOS 6.0. It has been replaced with the `NSTextAlignment` enum. Newer versions of the compiler (with newer versions of Xcode) are more strict about this.

Since your Base SDK is iOS 6.1 (based on the title of your question), the compiler complains that you are using the wrong enum value.

Your Deployment Target has no bearing on the compiler messages. The good news is that the newer enum is backward compatible with the older enum as long as you stick to the `Left`, `Center`, and `Right` values.

Change your code to:

```
_cartaServiziLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

and your code will compile and it will work with iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: Just to be clear, iOS 6 did *two* things: it deprecated UITextAlignment, and it introduced the notion of an enum type that can actually be type-checked. The runtime doesn't care what "enum type" you use: it looks at the integer value and that's that. But the iOS 6 compiler (Xcode 4.5 and later) is able to warn you. You *could* just ignore the warning. But don't!

Comment: @matt There is no iOS 6 compiler. There is the LLVM compiler. The newer version of the compiler added support for enum type checking. It just so happens that this updated compiler started with Xcode 4.5 which just so happens to support iOS 6.0.

Comment: I know; just simplifying for the OP.